# Read from SCSI bus with software

Tags: windbg, scsi

I am in the process of making a hardware control interface for my vintage  Yamaha CBX-D5 audio recording processor. using MIDI SysEx commands. This is well under way and I managed to find out most of it's inner workings. I programmed SysEx in Arduino to send over the MIDI bus.

But now I would like to read from it's SCSI bus in a software solution. I mean there are expensive hardware solutions out there, but these are out of reach for me.. so there must be a way to intercept the startup Command structure being sent over the SCSI bus so I can program it in a ATMEGA328P chip or something.

Anyone out there that knows how to achieve that one? I do have Logic Audio Platinium that sends those SCSI commands, but don't know how to read and interpret SCSI Command Description Blocks. Maybe there is a way to intercept it on the MacBook Bronze that runs it..

Comment: This might better fit on http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There's the SCSIKD extension. Perhaps that helps.

Comment: OK thanks Thomas I'll try that when I am on the SCSI software project again. I finished the hardware project and use it every day in my studio.